# Hosting site with Github and Vercel, images won't show up

Tags: html, css, github, vercel

I'm making a website that will be hosted on vercel with the files on github and my image isn't visible:

[image]

My file structure on my github is:

- Tom-Odell-V2

  - assets

    - images

And this is what I have in my html:

```
<img src="https://tom-odell-v2.vercel.app/assets/images/tom-odell-album-coverart.jpg" class="album-cover">
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction as I've tried a few different solutions suggested on here and none have seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given wrong image source link in your HTML code.

Perhaps you have missed the `/assets/` path in your link.  It should be

```html
<section id="music"class="landing">
    <img src="../assets/images/tom-odell-album-coverart.jpg" class="album-cover">
</section>
```

but you have given :

```html
<section id="music"class="landing">
    <img src="../images/tom-odell-album-coverart.jpg" class="album-cover">
</section>
```

Comment: I think my changes aren't pushing to Vercel, because that is what I've put. I'll have to figure out if there is a way to force the changes. I will make sure that works and then see if this is correct but I believe this is the answer! Thank you!

Comment: You can try setting [deployment hooks](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git/deploy-hooks) to manual trigger a deployment for the latest commit..

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I never transferred my project to a Pro version so I hit the number of deployments I could make in a day. This is the correct answer tho! Thanks again!